# PHP: Undefined offset error

Tags: php, sql, arrays

The below-provided code is used to fill an array "data".

```
$query1="SELECT * FROM tab1, tab2 WHERE tab1.column1=tab2.column2;";
    $result1=DatabaseConnector::ExecuteQueryArray($query1);
    $data = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($result1 as $row):
        $data[] = array(
            array($i,array("xxx",' EE112',$row['column3'],'FT445'),"2004-03-01 10:00","2004-03-01 14:00"));
        $i++;
    endforeach;
```

When I try reading data from the array, the error "Undefined offset: 1" occurs. The funny thing is that when I filled "data" array using `$data =` and not `$data[] =`, there was no error, just the last row was filled. The error is produced by line `$bar = new GanttBar(..)`. I tried to substitute `$row['column3']` by some string "xxx", but there was the same error.

```
for($i=0; $i<count($data); ++$i) {
        $bar = new GanttBar($data[$i][0],$data[$i][1],$data[$i][2],$data[$i][3]);
        $graph->Add($bar);
    }
```

Comment: `var_dump` that array and you'll see...

Comment: I added the line var_dump($data); I'm using Zend Studio. Where can I see the output of var_dump? Sorry I'm newbie. I tried Debug Mode and also looked at Console. There is no message there.

Comment: Run the code and you're supposed to see what $data looks like. Then compare that with the way you iterate over its elements.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't

```
$data[] = array("xxx",' EE112',$row['column3'],'FT445',"2004-03-01 10:00","2004-03-01 14:00");
```

just enough, data structure should be as simple as possible.

Ok, if you want that structure.

```
$data[] = array(array("xxx",' EE112',$row['column3'],'FT445'),"2004-03-01 10:00","2004-03-01 14:00");
```

Then

```
foreach($data as $i => $var) {
    $bar = new GanttBar($i, $var[0], $var[1], $var[2]);
    $graph->Add($bar);
}
```

Comment: No, I'm working with jpGraph Gantt Chart and it requires specific input format. Well, if I manually fill the array "data", then everything works fine.

Comment: The second bit of code does not work with the third one - `$var` will be again an array containing an array. Use the first way to fill `$data` with the loop at the end.

Comment: @Niko, He wants `$var[0]` to be an array.

Comment: Ups, both your solution and mine are fine if I do $data[] = array($i,array(... The error was caused by $data[] = array(array($i,array(...

Comment: @KlausosKlausos Why do you need include `$i` in the $data, you could just use the `$i` in the second loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a very basic problem:

The foreach loop is creating a new subarray in $data for every row. But later on your code is trying to get three rows from each entry in $data - which never has been created. Therefore `$data[$i][1]` is always empty.

You might need to adjust your sql query to receive the data in the correct format from the beginning.

Comment: The problem is that the following code also is not fine: $bar = new GanttBar($i,"xxx","2010-10-10 10:05","2010-10-10 11:00"); Maybe there is the problem with count($data)? I don't understand why this code works for manually created "data" array: $data = array(array(...),array(...),array(...));

Comment: Show us an example of your manually created data and what you do with it. Then also show us what `print_r($row)` contains.